# About testing techniques

Tags: testing, methods, manual

I want some Testing information about my application.
Which testing method is suitable for my application page.

In my page contains 200 check boxes. on click on check box, one new page open with different URL.
*Note: all check boxes having different URL.

So, please anyone help me out to find which testing method is suitable.
and how can i test my this page with less effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing techniques, I think here are some expectation.

Techniques should focus on functional testing and reduce efforts of regression testing. From my experience, You should focus on Manual and Automation techniques.

Manual Efforts

1. If page have more than 200 check box, First question is it necessary to have 200 check box on one page, It will not good user experience. You can filed defect against requirement and product development team. Discussion begin
2. To verify look and feel of 200 checkbox and page, I will always focus on some QA notes that help everyone team to understand testing efforts that include browser specification and if page is responsive than which are different size of screen you are going to test
3. I will prefer to write Cucumber Scenario in Gherkin Language using Given/When and Then [Cucumber Source](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference)
4. Scenario should be written in way that can help you to automate

Automation Efforts

1. I would recommand you to use selenium and choose any programming lanague(C#,PHP,Java,JavaScript,perl,Ruby,Python and other many) for automation.
2. You already have scenario and You can automate easily
3. Few things should be part of automation like deep verification that page is loaded successfully, title of page are matching and take snapshot if page is not loaded or during exception.  Automation code should execute against any browser.

This is good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for you is to use [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) and [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), but i don't know if you are familiar with the `Ruby`language as you didn't talk about any programming language you'd like to use.

In order to achieve this workflow (click on a checkbox and check for the url), you should do something like this

```
describe "A test to", :js => true do
 it "click on a checkbox and check for the url" do
  visit("http://your_url") //to visit your page
  page.check('the ID or the NAME of the checkbox') //to click on the checkbox
  within_window(switch_to_window(windows.last)) do //to focus on the new opened page
   expect(current_url).to eq('http://the_expected_url') //to check the url
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Hello fabersky, but i don't have any idea about Ruby